# Did Hans Muller ever publish "Mastering JList Programming" as promised?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

This [article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/tech_topics/jlist_1/jlist.html) was Part 1 of a two part article.

I cannot find Part 2, "Mastering JList Programming". 
Google cannot find it.

Did it get lost in the Oracle-Sun move, or was it never published?

Comment: You might be waiting a while.  It's been 50 years next month, and I'm still waiting for "Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation by Machine, Part II"!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he did, because all this information can be found in offical Java tutorials. Here is the link to  the one for JList:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html